# why the sql query is different on that linq query when run on c# and on vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

if I run this under c#

```
from p in Addresses where p.Address2 == null select p.AddressID
```

it generate this query

```
SELECT [t0].[AddressID]
FROM [dbo].[Address] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Address2] IS NULL
```

if I run this under vb.net

```
from p in Addresses where p.Address2 = nothing select p.AddressID
```

it generate this query

```
SELECT [t0].[AddressID]
FROM [dbo].[Address] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Address2] = ''
```

**p.Address2** is a varchar field that accept null value

why vb.net is "wrong" ?

Comment: Untested, but should it not be `from p in Addresses where p.Address2 is nothing select p.AddressID`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in VB, null checks are controlled with "is" keyword.

try this;

```
from p in Addresses where p.Address2 is nothing select p.AddressID
```